# A text to be introduced after n records in crystal report using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I am trying to create a question paper in crystal report using vb.net 2005
what I did is , I created a table in ms-access with the following columns

```
Unit No     Number
Mark        Number
Question    Text
```

I am entering three marks 1,6,12. I placed a datagridview control with check box column. when I check the question, I get it and pass it to dataset and then to crystal report. My problem is I want the report to be like this

```
Part - A
Answer any 20 Question                      20 X 1= 20
1.Define os.
2.Define semaphore

...
...
20.Define Linux.
(After 20 records I have to insert the following)
Part - B
Answer any 6 Question.
21. Explain architecture of os?
```

Kindly help me in this regards 
Advance thanks for ur help
Regards
Joseph Albert

Answer (score 0):

`Note: I have no knowledge on vb.net but using below way you can do it in crystal reports as a standalone application`

Place your questions in detail section and count the records till `n` and reset the record count after the `n`.

1. First create 2 detail sections `detail a` and `detail b`. use `detail a` to print questions and use `detail b` to insert a text.
2. Create a formula `@reset` and place it in `Detail b` and `supress`. Place the text you wish in `detail b` and don't supress

   ```
   Shared Numbervar reset;

   if reset=n  //your count example 20
   then reset:=0
   ```
3. Now create a formula `@Count` and place it in `detail a`.

   ```
   Shared Numbervar reset;
   reset:=reset+1
   ```
4. Go to `supress` of the `detail b` and write below code:

   ```
   EvaluateAfter({@Count});
   if {@Count}=n // n means your number here example 20
   then false
   else true
   ```

This will make sure that for every `n` records you can display text you require.